# Bash: change variable defined at top of script

Tags: bash

At the top of my script I have some variables defined like so

```
# Start Variables
defaultmap="de_dust2"
port="27015"
sourcetvport="27020"
clientport="27005"
maxplayers="16"
ip="0.0.0.0"
parms="-game csgo -usercon +map ${defaultmap} -strictportbind -ip ${ip} -port ${port} +clientport ${clientport} +tv_port ${sourcetvport} -maxplayers ${maxplayers}"
```

I have a function fn_`autoip` that is designed to change `${ip}` if it is set to `0.0.0.0` to the network card IP (somthing like 192.168.1.2). However it is not changing this.

My guess is that it is not changing `${ip}` because is is within another variable `${parms}` that was already defined when `${ip}` was `0.0.0.0`. This is how it is executed:

```
fn_debugserver(){
fn_autoip
${executable} ${parms}
}
```

Is there a way where `${parms}` can be 'reloaded' with the new `${ip}` from `fn_autoip`?

This is from [my project on GitHub](https://github.com/dgibbs64/linuxgameservers)

Comment: Why do you have a `params` var set at the beginning of the file?

Comment: All variables I want to user to easily see and change are at the top. It just makes things much easier.

Comment: And `params` is a variable that the users should easily see?

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping the value of a variable with double quotes is not enough to protect any nested variable names. So what's happening is you're setting `$params`, but when your program executes, `$params` is having those variables expanded, so they're gone when you evaluate `$params` later on.

#### Example

Say we have this situation, similar to yours.

```
$ nested_var="nested secret"
$ params="the value is: ${nested_var}"
```

When we evaluate these variables:

```
$ echo $nested_var
nested secret
$ echo $params
the value is: nested secret
```

So we can see that the variable in `$params` definition has already been expanded, so it's no longer in the form `$nested_var`, it's now `netsted_secret`.

Using single quotes would help protect `$params` definition.

```
$ params='the value is: $nested_var'
$ echo $params
the value is: $nested_var
```

But now the question is how do we tell Bash to expand this variable, later on. Here's where you could use the command `eval`.

```
$ nested_var="nested secret"
$ eval "echo $params"
the value is: nested secret
```

Changing `$nested_var`:

```
$ nested_var="another nested secret"
$ eval "echo $params"
the value is: another nested secret
```

The `eval` command has a [bad rep though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead). So I think I would encourage you to do what you're trying using functions instead.

#### Alternative method

I would be tempted to create a function that you pass into it parameters, and the function would return constructed `$params` string back.

#### Example

```
$ genparam () { printf -- "-game csgo -usercon +map %s -strictportbind -ip %s -port %s +clientport %s +tv_port %s -maxplayers %s\n" "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6";  }
```

Here's an expanded view of that one-liner:

```
$ genparam () { 
    printf -- "-game csgo -usercon +map %s -strictportbind -ip %s -port %s +clientport %s +tv_port %s -maxplayers %s\n" \
       "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6";    \
}
```

Now when we call our function `genparm()` we pass it the arguments that we want it to use like so:

```
$ genparam $defaultmap $ip $port $clientport $sourcetvport $maxplayers
-game csgo -usercon +map de_dust2 -strictportbind -ip 0.0.0.0 -port 27015 +clientport 27005 +tv_port 27020 -maxplayers 16
```

Comment: Wow thanks for this answer. I will have a good read of this later on to make sure I understand this :D

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best solution, but you can transform you variable into a function and use it like this

```
parms () {
  echo "-game csgo -usercon +map ${defaultmap} -strictportbind -ip ${ip} -port ${port} +clientport ${clientport} +tv_port ${sourcetvport} -maxplayers ${maxplayers}"
}

#...

fn_debugserver() {
  fn_autoip
  $executable $(params)
}
```

Comment: This does work well. However I am hoping there is another option if possible. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to set parms after fn_autoip is run (or at the end of that function).  The variables are set in the order they show up in the file.

You 'reload' the variable by setting it again.